# error code ELIFECYCLE, npm start does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I can't understand why `npm start` does not work in my project. Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~prestart: react-routing@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: react-routing@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Frogi\Desktop\Новая папка\React-IT-KAMASUTRA\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;Y:\JDK\bin;E:\myWorkplace\sort\nodeJS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin; C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\mingw53_32\bin;C:\Users\Frogi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Frogi\AppData\Local\atom\bin
9 verbose lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Frogi\Desktop\Новая папка\React-IT-KAMASUTRA
10 silly lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react-routing@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: react-routing@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid react-routing@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Frogi\Desktop\Новая папка\React-IT-KAMASUTRA
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-routing@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-routing@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Project: https://github.com/DarkKeksik/React-IT-KAMASUTRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, solution is '**npm install react-scripts@2.1.8**'.

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below-

```
npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ 
npm install --registry=https://custom.npm.registry.com/
```

and then-

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Do you have your package.json in place?

Comment: Yes it is, link in project (https://github.com/DarkKeksik/React-IT-KAMASUTRA)

Comment: I using "npx create-react-app" and "npm start", but i get error "code ELIFECYCLE error 1"

Comment: Try npm cache clean --force. If this does not work, probably you can try deleting the node_modules and npm i again.

Comment: I have tried, but not work (file lock also deleted)